# android application and communication with asterisk server

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to develop an application voip android drawing mainly from the famous application  "CSipSimple"  and in addition to sending and receiving audio and video call I'll try to draw the position of a client using  ip address  :the information of  geo locations  identified from smart phone will be forwarded to the Asterisk server then he  charge  to store it  in its MySQL database.) and therefore access to the asterisk  's console   from the device and  then those informations of  geolocation will be recovered at the request of a customer. Please quelque'un can help me with links or ideas to start I will be really grateful. thank you in advance

Comment: Questions asking for links and ideas are off-topic here. In French: les questions demandant des liens et des idées sont hors-sujet ici.

Answer (score 0):

What is your blocking problem here?

-For SIP audio/video use CSipSimple.

-From Asterisk, just store the caller/called party IP with the CDR into your database.

-For GeoIP you can use your own database (these kind of tables can be downloaded from various sources) or you can use a service (there are a few xml or json based services providing these info).

-For the display you can use google map (some javascript code will be needed)